# Will glog content been executed if does not meet required level

Tags: go

The question is simple, I have a log like this:

```
glog.v(5).Infof("xxx %v", getLogContent())
```

But my `getLogContent()` is **a time consuming** method, so I want to ask: will `getLogContent()` been executed or not when my program does not meet v(5) level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

You should add an if statement if you don't want `getLogContent()` to run

```
if glog.V(5) {
    glog.V(5).Infof("xxx %v", getLogContent())
}
```

Go evaluates all arguments, so `getLogContent` will get called but the output will not be logged if the verbosity level has not been met.

Answer (score 0):

I was curious and playing around with this. I don't know if this would work for you but it's interesting.

By using a lambda function, and making a function type that implements the `Stringer` interface, the Go format library will call it when it needs to print it.

I could not find a way I really liked to create the function type, maybe someone else knows some better trick.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "time"
)

type thing func() string

func (t thing) String() string {
    return t()
}

func toThing(f func() string) thing {
    return f
}

func maybePrint(p bool, args ...interface{}) {
    if p {
        fmt.Println(args...)
    }
}

func main() {
    maybePrint(len(os.Args) > 2, "testing", toThing(func() string {
        fmt.Println("Calculating big thing")
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
        return "test"
    }))
}
```